# How can I optimize my variables in this case?

Tags: javascript

So I'm basically trying to save the input information in a variable and put it in the end as a result. but I'm having some difficulties in relation to the variables and the way I distribute this at the end, mainly in the checkbox question... Could you guys give me some tips?

```
    // Answers
    
    var answer1 = "",
        answer2 = "",
        answer3modern = "",
        answer3serious = "",
        answer3pesado = "",
        answer3leve = "",
        answer3descontraido = "",
        answer3popular = "",
        answer3singular = "",
        answer3conservador = "",
        answer4 = "",
        answer5 = "",
        answer6A = "",
        answer6B = "",
        answerS1 = "";
    
    
    };
    function next3(){
        var modern = document.getElementById('modern');
        var serious = document.getElementById('serious');
        var pesado = document.getElementById('pesado');
        var leve = document.getElementById('leve');
        var descontraido = document.getElementById('descontraido');
        var popular = document.getElementById('popular');
        var singular = document.getElementById('singular');
        var conservador = document.getElementById('conservador');
        if(modern.checked == true){
            answer3modern = "Moderno"
        };
        if(serious.checked == true){
            answer3serious = "Sério"
        };
    };
    function back3(){
        answer3modern = "";
        answer3serious = "";
        answer3pesado = "";
        answer3leve = "";
        answer3descontraido = "";
        answer3popular = "";
        answer3singular = "";
        answer3conservador = "";
        question3.style.display = 'block';
        question4.style.display = 'none';
    };        
        if(answer1 != ""){
            document.getElementById('company-name').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('companyname').innerHTML = answer1;
        }
        if(answer2 != ""){
            document.getElementById('niche').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('ramo').innerHTML = answer2;
        }
    
        results.style.display = 'block';
    };
```

Comment: I had to cut some parts of the code :(.....

Comment: https://devinduct.com/blogpost/22/javascript-clean-code-best-practices —> I really recommend you to read this post. It won’t take long and it will teach you alot about cleaning up your code and making code that looks clean from the beginning

Comment: @VitorFreitas *I had to cut some parts of the code :(*,  well those parts are important!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do something like this:

```js
var answer1 = answer2 = answer3modern = answer3serious = answer3pesado = answer3leve = answer3descontraido = answer3popular = answer3singular = answer3conservador = answer4 = answer5 = answer6A = answer6B = answerS1 = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to see the HTML code as well, but just by looking at the js you could use a form in the HTML page with all those inputs inside and get all those values as an associative array by using:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var data = new FormData(form);
```

or with JQuery:

```
var data = $("form").serialize();
```